# Android: layout same height as text

Tags: android

I am banging my head against the wall, because I do not understand this!

I need the blue part layout the same height of the contained red text.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

This is my XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/single_margin"
            android:background="@color/post_icons_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/single_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/primary_brand_color"
            android:id="@+id/separator_continer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:background="@color/secondary_brand_color" />

            <TextView
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:background="@color/accent_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="or"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_brand_color" />


            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:background="@color/secondary_brand_color" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gallery_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/post_icons_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/double_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/single_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_gallery" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: What is the id of that blue part?

Comment: remove padding bottom in your camera linear layout and check what you get. The upper portion will get removed.

Comment: @KishorPawar `separator_continer`

Comment: post your code properly with color and dimen

Comment: Tnx that solution help me as well

Comment: please include your dimensions to help you specifically

Answer (score 1):

Looks like none of the answer is going to work so here's my catch.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- change here if you want the layout to cover the full screen -->
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" <!-- change here -->
        android:layout_weight="0.5"> <!-- change here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/separator_continer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gallery_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" <!-- change here -->
        android:layout_weight="0.5"> <!-- change here -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I copied only the parts that need to be changed, of course you don't have to delete the inner views. You just need to change the attributes I changed.

This way the outer `LinearLayout` firstly computes the dimension of the center view, which has no `layout_weight` attributes, and lays it down; then the remaining space is divided equally between `camera_container` and `gallery_container`.

Answer (score 0):

your parent i.e. First linear vertical layout android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of wrap_content

Comment: your parent i.e. First linear vertical layout android:layout_width="match_parent" instead of wrap_content

Comment: Tnx that solution help me as well

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout like this

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/single_margin"
        android:background="@color/post_icons_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/double_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/single_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/primary_brand_color"
        android:id="@+id/separator_continer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="@color/secondary_brand_color" />

        <TextView
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="matchparent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@color/accent_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="or"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_brand_color" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="@color/secondary_brand_color" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gallery_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/post_icons_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/single_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/double_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/double_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/single_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_gallery" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you try it now @LisaAnne

Answer (score 0):

Use this Layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ff00">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OR" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nope Jafar, you are wrong, the `android:weightSum` is applied to the children

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use ,

```
android:layout_marginTop="Xdp"
android:layout_marginBottom="Xdp"
```

for your textview.

Comment: Tried `android:layout_marginTop="0dp"` `android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"` but no success :-((

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Option 1:

```
android:minHeight="50dp"
```

in your centre textView

Option 2:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/separator_continer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
/>

        <TextView
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="or"
/>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gallery_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please check after adding with your background resources

Comment: Abhishek, that is not an option unfortunately

Comment: then try option 2 @Lisa